# Easy Python Script to work in Excel

Tags: python, excel

Im a beginner programmer and I'm trying to write a Python script 
that
1) open the current xlsx excel file
2) coverts all lower cases string values into upper case
3) saves the file with a new name.

the simple the script the better
I have done nothing so far ! I DONT KNOW WHERE TO START

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Isnt Excel files, more or less just a formatted text document read in a certain way?   I feel this can be done inside of what?   10 lines of code?

Comment: @Fallenreaper sure, but all of computing is just two numbers read a certain way, so any turing complete problem should be solvable in a few lines of code too :)

Comment: start by the beginning. I quote you `open the current xlsx file`. google `open xlsx python` yields quite a few answers.

Comment: True.   Anyways, OP, go to pythons website, and take a look at File I/O.  Thats your start.

Answer (score 2):

```
import xlrd, xlwt
oldbook = xlrd.open_workbook('bar.xlsx')
newbook = xlwt.Workbook() 

for sheetname in oldbook.sheet_names():
    oldsheet = oldbook.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    newsheet = newbook.add_sheet(sheetname)
    for ii in range(oldsheet.nrows):
        for jj in range(oldsheet.ncols):
             newsheet.write(ii, jj, str(oldsheet.cell_value(ii, jj)).upper())


newbook.save("foo.xlsx")
```